# CSS- How'd they do that without Absolute Positioning and Z-index?

Tags: css, html

I'm a novice, but not entirely new to CSS and coding.  Over the last 6 months or so I have come a LONG WAY with my coding.  A few weeks ago I came across a website with a really cool layout.  In particular, the TigerHawk logo sat across (or at least appeared to) several non-AP Divs and I cannot seem to figure out how they did it.  I'm pretty sure they are not AP Divs because of how the divs change position when I expand the page, etc.

Can someone enlighten me on how it was done without using AP divs?  I'm pretty sure I could replicate it using AP divs and adjusting the Z-index so that the logo hovered over the top of the divs I need it to, but such a layout is too rigid for what I am looking to do.

Here is the link to the hawkeyesports.com website where the TigerHawk logo sits over the other divs.   [Check out hawkeyesports.com for some really cool CSS I am trying to figure out.](http://www.hawkeyesports.com/)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#mast-logo` is absolutely positioned.

```
#mast-logo {
  background: url("http://grfx.cstv.com/schools/iowa/graphics/iowa-10-logo.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  height: 133px;
  left: -13px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  width: 198px;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

[It is not really difficult to do](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/3jUgF/), once you get the hang of `absolute` and `relative` positioning.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I didn't think that with AP Div the div would move when expanding the page, etc?  And thanks for the link!

Comment: @LawGen Its parent has `position: relative`, which means the offsets you supply to any absolutely positioned children are *relative* to it.

Comment: Ahhh...I see (so i think).  The link and explanation are very helpful and I GREATLY appreciate it!

Comment: @LawGen No worries, feel free to give me the green tick :)

Comment: @LawGen None of the divs are expanding as far as I can tell. The site appears to be fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

The logo that is next to the menu has this CSS according to firebug:

```
#mast-logo {
-moz-background-clip:border;
-moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
-moz-background-origin:padding;
background:transparent url(http://grfx.cstv.com/schools/iowa/graphics/iowa-10-logo.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
height:133px;
left:-13px;
position:absolute;
top:-4px;
width:198px;
z-index:200;
}
```

Comment: Firebug...never heard of it, but will look into it! Wow, so it is Absolute positioned....? So this "Firebug" allows us to peak at a sites CSS? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, you can debug Javascript, view CSS, etc.  Firebug is a must have.  Don't forget to mark as answer. :)